# How do I make this Metabox show current DB value?

Tags: php, plugin-development, database, metabox

```
<p>
    <?php
        $options = get_option( 'city' );
        $names = explode( PHP_EOL, $options );
        ?>
        <label for="City" class="timeshare-row-title"><?php _e( 'City:', 'timeshare-textdomain' )?></label>
        <select name="city" id="city">
        <?php foreach ( $names as $name ) {
            printf(
                '<option value="%s" selected="selected">%s</option>',
                $name,
                $name
            );
        } ?>

        </select>
</p>
```

Save function:

```
 if( isset( $_POST[ 'city' ] ) ) {
    update_post_meta( $post_id, 'city', sanitize_text_field( $_POST[ 'city' ] ) );
}
```

This is code used for a working select metabox, this one is done with hard coded optios.

```
<p>
    <label for="beds" class="timeshare-row-title"><?php _e( 'Bedrooms:', 'timeshare-textdomain' )?></label>
    <select name="beds" id="beds">
        <option value="1" <?php if ( isset ( $timeshare_stored_meta['beds'] ) ) selected( $timeshare_stored_meta['beds'][0], '1' ); ?>><?php _e( '1', 'timeshare-textdomain' )?></option>';
        <option value="2" <?php if ( isset ( $timeshare_stored_meta['beds'] ) ) selected( $timeshare_stored_meta['beds'][0], '2' ); ?>><?php _e( '2', 'timeshare-textdomain' )?></option>';
        <option value="3" <?php if ( isset ( $timeshare_stored_meta['beds'] ) ) selected( $timeshare_stored_meta['beds'][0], '3' ); ?>><?php _e( '3', 'timeshare-textdomain' )?></option>';
        <option value="4" <?php if ( isset ( $timeshare_stored_meta['beds'] ) ) selected( $timeshare_stored_meta['beds'][0], '4' ); ?>><?php _e( '4', 'timeshare-textdomain' )?></option>';
    </select>
</p>

and the save code for it:
     // Checks for input and saves if needed
    if( isset( $_POST[ 'beds' ] ) ) {
    update_post_meta( $post_id, 'beds', $_POST[ 'beds' ] );
}
```

Save function:

```
function timeshare_meta_save( $post_id ) {

// Checks save status
$is_autosave = wp_is_post_autosave( $post_id );
$is_revision = wp_is_post_revision( $post_id );
$is_valid_nonce = ( isset( $_POST[ 'timeshare_nonce' ] ) && wp_verify_nonce( $_POST[ 'timeshare_nonce' ], basename( __FILE__ ) ) ) ? 'true' : 'false';

// Exits script depending on save status
if ( $is_autosave || $is_revision || !$is_valid_nonce ) {
    return;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your posted Github files, the function that prints the meta box is this

```
function timeshare_meta_callback( $post ) {
```

As you can see, `$post` is passed to this function. It's a [WP_Post](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Post) Object which contains all the information of that post.

WP_Post has a member variable named `ID`, which is needed to get the current post meta value that is saved. So, you need to do this get the post id

```
$post_id = $post->ID;
```

Here's the complete code

```
<p>
    <?php
        $post_id = $post->ID;
        $options = get_option( 'city' );
        $city_value = get_post_meta( $post_id, 'city', true );
        $names = explode( PHP_EOL, $options );
        ?>
        <label for="City" class="timeshare-row-title"><?php _e( 'City:', 'timeshare-textdomain' )?></label>
        <select name="city" id="city">
        <?php foreach ( $names as $name ) {
            printf(
                '<option value="%s" %s>%s</option>',
                $name,
                selected($name, $city_value, false),
                $name
            );
        } ?>

        </select>
</p>
```

Contrarily during saving only post id is passed, which can be seen from here.

```
function timeshare_meta_save( $post_id ) {
```

So, you could do this to save the post meta value directly

```
    if( isset( $_POST[ 'city' ] ) ) {
        update_post_meta( $post_id, 'city', sanitize_text_field( $_POST[ 'city' ] ) );
    }
```

Comment: @sakibmoon-still a no go, it defaults to the first item in the created list.

Comment: @JohnLucey I thought that you are saving the option as 'city', but as it turns out you are saving the whole city in that option field. Please post the code of how are you saving them in the db.

Comment: In the Database I can see the field value changes when I change the choice. The DB is being updated currently. Its the metabox that is not. I do not know if this matters but the select box values are being generated from a textarea in my Plugin Settings page. Hence the get_options usage.

Comment: @sakibmoon- I updated the code to show the corresponding save code.

Comment: @JohnLucey I've updated the code.

Comment: @sakibmoon-I added the new code and now I get an error:debug is turned on. Error is: Notice: Undefined variable: post_id in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/rcipg/wp-content/plugins/simple_timeshare/meta_box.php on line 64. It is saying $post_id is undefined. I wish there was a way you could see the entire file. I added code for a working select metabox to the code window for you to look at.

Comment: @JohnLucey it's the same `$post_id` variable that is used here: `update_post_meta( $post_id, 'city', sanitize_text_field( $_POST[ 'city' ] ) );`. I'm not sure where you are using this piece of code. But initializing that variable before `$city_value = get_post_meta( $post_id, 'city', true );` should do the trick.

Comment: added code to show where the occurrence is. It happens at the end of the file as part of the save function. Is it possible for me to put this on Github so you can better understand what I have happening in this file? or is that not allowed?

Comment: I have gone ahead and added the files to GitHub, the file we are working in is metabox.php. https://github.com/jlucey01/simple_timeshare

Comment: @JohnLucey that will help. Please paste the github link

Comment: @sakibmoon-i just want to take a second to say thank you for sticking out with me. I am fairly new to WordPress plugin build and design, have built many custom templates. This is my first go at a plugin and this animal has been interesting and fun. But this one issue has been my biggest challenge so I want you to know that if not for people like you, people like me would probably give up. Thank you... I posted the link in my prior comment, no laughing at me coding... Lol

Comment: @JohnLucey I've updated the code. I would suggest you to go over the hooks and filter that you are using over codex to get more details on how they work. Once you've got the understanding of them, you will make great progress. Try to go over the documentation first. They have tons of good information and example to get you started.

Comment: Ok so this is closer for sure, if I choose the last option or the first option in the list it keeps them. Anything between it does not bring the value up?

Comment: However the database values do continue to update, so no matter what choice I make in the drop down it does write the value back to the database.

Comment: @JohnLucey this should work. One thing, you don't need to use sanitize_text_field when you are updating the post meta. Wordpress will do that for you. You can debug whether the correct value is getting saved in the database.

Comment: @sakibmoon-Database updates correctly, but the select box still does not show post data. If I choose the last option in the list it holds, if I choose the first option in the list it holds. Anything in between it defaults back to the first item in the list. I agree with you that it should work but it does not. I took it a step further and removed everything I could take out of my original file and it still does the same thing.

Comment: @sakibmoon-OK so just a small update, I figured out how to use Var_dump() and Debug. I can see the database update but the selected item is not updating. I checked all our variables with Var_dump() and they do return the expected values. It is almost like the select statement is being ignored.